# How to know where a react component is used/imported?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I just started working on a react project which has a relatively larger code base. How can I find all references of a class or a function among whole project. I'm using vscode which I found that I can only find reference within the same file.

Comment: Search your codebase for its name, or remove it and build and see which components error

Comment: Are you referring to VSCode's built-in "Find all References" when right clicking on a variable name? If so, you may need to set up a jsconfig.json (or tsconfig.json if you're using TS) in order to help VSCode resolve paths. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig

Comment: yes, Mitch. That's what I mean.Thanks